# ubuntu 20.04 install apache2 version 2.2.x

Tags: 20.04, apache2

Don't ask me why but I need to install apache2 version 2.2.29 on linux Ubuntu 20.04.

```
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.29.tar.bz2
tar -xf httpd-2.2.29.tar.bz2
cd httpd-2.2.29/
./configure
make
make install
```

But I get error and can't install apache2.

How can we install apache2 2.2.29 on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Edit your question and copy/paste the text of the error.

Comment: If you need a specific version of any given software, the only *realistic* way to accomplish the goal while also keeping the OS up to date would be to use [Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd). That said, there does not seem to be one for that specific version of Apache. [2.2.31 is the oldest version](https://hub.docker.com/layers/httpd/library/httpd/2.2.31/images/sha256-c8a7fb36e3abfc42f15f2a2a9293f1768a5b568fd7ac51546f0055e399c29aef?context=explore) that is currently available, and it has not been checked for vulnerabilities in quite some time ...

Comment: it doesn't matter if version is 2.2.29 or 2.2.31, only matters to be 2.2.x. As I said so, this is not question "Why I need this", it is question "Is this possible" and If it is, "why I can't, why I get errors".

Comment: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache => Error: 
"configure: error: in `/home/httpd-2.2.29/srclib/apr':"
"configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH"